# How to get the correct row id, in a onActiveCellChanged event, from a filtered Slickgrid

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

I'm using the latest SlickGrid, with dataView.

I subscribe to the `onActiveCellChanged` event to react to a user selecting a row, and get the cell contents of the first column with:

```
grid.onActiveCellChanged.subscribe(function(e, args)
{
    var cell = args.cell;
    var row = args.row;
    vat cell_contents = data[row][grid.getColumns()[0].field];
```

This works perfectly until I filter the table. Then args.row doesn't match the row in the data table.

How can I map the filtered row number (given in the event), to the actual row of the data that I want to read?

i.e. A filtered grid could yield one row of data, but could actually be row ten of the actual data table. I need to be able to read the data in the visible row selected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After numerous attempts, I finally managed to do this. For anyone else that comes looking, what I did was:

```
    grid.onActiveCellChanged.subscribe(function(e, args)
    {
        var cell = args.cell;
        var row = args.row;

        var row_data = dataView.getItem(row);  // Read from dataView not the grid data
        var cell_contents = row_data['id'];
```

This solution compensates for re-ordered columns as well as filtered rows.